# Laravel Password Forget skipping Notifications

Tags: php, laravel, email, notifications

Using Laravel 5.3.* laravel uses the Notifications to SEND a password reset mail to the user. Since we need to have a different approach on sending e-mails out of laravel, I cannot use notifications.

How can I modify/override the send function at the Password Forget.
Do I still need to:

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    //$this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));  
    own mailing system here....
}
```

or do I need a diffrent approch to this?

This is what I found:

```
 $user = User::where('email', 'example@name.com' )->first();
 $password_broker = app(PasswordBroker::class); //so we can have dependency injection
 $token = $password_broker->createToken($user); //create reset password token
```

Our own "mail send" looks like this (this is for user register):

```
$this->sendUserEmail( $user->id, trans('user.registration_confirmation_email_subject'), 'emails.registration_confirmation',
                array('registrationKey' => $user->registration_key) );
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to use your own SMTP server?

Comment: No, we have a completely diffrent mail approch using worker and jobs. Actually ist just a different mail send function that I need to implement - I added our mailsend function